# a.nativeSelection is null TinyMCE Editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a tinyMCE editor embedded in my page. At times it gets loaded find. Other times it throws "a.nativeSelection is null".

What could be wrong?

Comment: Post some code (How you embedded the TinyMCE editor), that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used multiple tinyMCE editors in same page with same id for the textarea controls over which tinyMCE is applied. This leads to problems of editor not loading perfectly. I have now modified my code to clear the existing editor off the textarea and load the new one. This solved it.